# Installation on Intel 240 GB SSD

Tags: ssd

Attempting to install "Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-amd64" to an Intel 240 GB SSD formatted w / one partition NTFS.  After booting Ubuntu from a DVD (to which the ISO is burned), I get to the screen for "Something Else" then select the Intel SSD.  From this point the install messages tell me to make changes to the partition(?).  Tried several things at that point to no avail.
Is this installation possible?  Thanks ahead, LSW1491

Comment: You need to change partitions as Ubuntu uses ext4 by default and will not install to NTFS. Are there any other drives in your computer? If so then make sure you do **not** format them while choosing "something else" if you want to keep your data. In any case please always **backup** before you change partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If Ubuntu is the only Operating System you wish to install, select the option "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu". This is recommended for beginners.

However, if you wish to change the amount of swap etc. you will have to manually partition the drive. For more information on that, you can refer to these pages - [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes) [2](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/partitioning)